# NSMenuItem with full-width image

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsimage, nsmenu

I would like to add an `NSMenuItem` containing only an image to an (already populated) `NSMenu`. The image shall span the maximum possible width without changing the menu's current width. (It has to be full-width because it may contain left- and right-aligned elements.)

I found the following, but it seems those are not enough:

- [imageAndTitleWidth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuview/1500262-imageandtitlewidth?language=objc) seems to be usefull, but is deprecated.
- [`NSMenu::size`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenu/1518185-size) could help if I had a way to compute the left and right margin, but I could not find something like this.

So, is there a way to have the image span the whole menu's width?